# Nginx server is unable to start when i try to deploy a static website

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress, nginx-config, nginx-location

## i have captures on the code of config file and the exact location and the error itself

[The error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDZVL.png)
[The config script and the exact location of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii9xR.png)

i've tried to change port but it doesn't work
i've created another config file thinking it's syntax error but it doesn't work either and i even changed listen :*80 to listen80 but nothing works.

what i want to do is to deploy the website and do 3 replicas.

Answer (score 0):

The keywords have to be separated by space from their values.
If you use the IP part of the declaration, you have to separate the port by `:`

instead of

```
listen*80 default_server;
listen[::]:80 default_server;
```

write

```
listen  *:80  default_server;
listen  [::]:80  default_server;
```

But for your example, this should be enough:

```
listen  80  default_server;
```

Same thing comes to

- `location /{` –> `location  /  {`
- `server{` -> `server {`

Lax syntax is the first source for problems. It is very helpful to structure by intents:

```
server {
    listen      80  default_server;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    root        /var/www/website/html/;

    location / {
        index       index.html;
    }
}
```

Preferably you should have defined the root directly in the server root definitions. So I also moved the `root` statement.

Comment: Well i still knowing how to use it  so it happens and thank  you for your answer i'll try it and let  you know.also can you explain more about the root definition ?

Comment: You can define multiple times `location`  with different paths or regex. If required you can define a different root within a `location` container, for example to store huge media files on a different filesystem. — But it's quite usefull to have the mother of all "DOCUMENT_ROOT"  (= root) defined. And this is in the base of the `server { }` container.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: unfortunalty it hasn't solved yet, i even recreated the file more than once but it doesn't work .

Comment: What do the logs say? Perhaps you should enable the nginx log: `error_log /var/log/nginx-error.log info;`

Comment: Well what i have done is that i created it in default folder html near default.html

Comment: Please add the error_log. Everything else is more or less blind guessing. And is the tag `nginx-reverse-proxy` and `nginx-ingress` by purpose? — In the current config is nothing about it.